# Unbiased Estimator

Tags: machine-learning

I have the following problem.
Given a data set E (containing info about age for example).
Consider two subsets of E, E1 containing age<40, and E2 containing age>=40.
If H is the solution provided by  a learning method using E1 as training set, is E2 an unbiased estimator for the True error of H ?

From Tom Mitchell machine learning:
*The estimation bias of an estimator Y for an arbitrary parameter p is E[y]-p.
If the estimation bias is zero, we say that Y is an unbiased estimator for p.
In order for errors(h) to give an unbiased estimate of errorv(h), the hypothesis h and sample
S must be chosen independently.*

I am having a little trouble answering the question, but I think it is not an unbiased estimator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that age is what you are predicting (the target of regression or classification) , the clear answer is NO. When the system is trained on E1 (age<40), in general, E2 (age>=40) is a biased dataset for estimating its error. Because the training set does not contain sufficient variations of the validation set (unless the model is very simple like linear). The right way is to choose E1 and E2 randomly from E.